# Function to compute Scallop Loss

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, windowing

I want to make a function that computes the value of the Scallop loss for a Rectangular, Hamming and Blackman window using the Scallop loss formula.
I have created a function but it only returns that answer 0, have I made an error?

```
function s_l = scallop loss(len)
window = rectwin(len);
num_total = 0;
den_total = 0;

for n = 0:len-1
    A1 = exp(-((1i*(n)*pi)/len));
    A2 = window(n+1)*A1;
    num = abs(A2);
    den = win(n+1);
    num_total = num_total + num;
    den_total = den_total + den:
end

result = 20*log(num_total/den_total);

s_l = result;
```

[image: Scallop Loss Formula]

Comment: Len is `N`? adn what is `w`? shouldn't you have another input in the function for `w[n]`?

Comment: your code returns an error `win` undefined. Can you please put the real code that runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a maths problem:

```
abs(sum(A)) != sum(abs(A))
```

They are not the same!

Change your code to:

```
window = rectwin(len);
num_total = 0;
den_total = 0;

for n = 0:len-1
    A1 = exp(-((1i*(n)*pi)/len));
    A2 = window(n+1)*A1;
    num = A2;                      % !!
    den = abs(window(n+1));        % you also forgot the abs  here
    num_total = num_total + num;
    den_total = den_total + den;
end
num_total=abs(num_total);    % !!
result = 20*log(num_total/den_total);

s_l = result;
```

Answer (score 2):

please change the log() function to log10(). without it the result is completely wrong :)

I mean this line:
**result = 20*log10*(num_total/den_total);**